# OneVsRestClassifier running too slow without any response

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I ran sklearn OneVsRestClassifier on my computer(8G MBP),but with no response for nearly 5 hours. The data scale is around 200 000.My jupyter notebook became In[*] after running with no error or warning.

I tried another code like this. It's speed is ok.

```
digits = load_digits()

x, y = digits.data, digits.target
y = label_binarize(y, classes=list(range(10)))
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
model = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear'))
clf = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
print  clf.score(x_train, y_train)
```

I wonder if this problem is caused by my code's error. Or have you ever met similar problems?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the scale of data is 200.000?' You could try to set 'verbose' to 1 on your estimators to get more input on what is going on.

Comment: Thank you, I mean there are 200000 samples

Comment: The documentation suggests that you might be out of luck in that case: "The implementation is based on libsvm. The fit time complexity is more than quadratic with the number of samples which makes it hard to scale to dataset with more than a couple of 10000 samples." Maybe limiting the number of iterations or choosing a different kernel could help.

Comment: Have you standardized your dataset? It will speed up the svm processing a bit.

Comment: Thank you all, I have standardized my dataset before, and I tried limited the number of iterations and chose linear kernel. It works but the result is not so satisfying. I need to change the model.